# Merging two network maps in networkx by unique labels

Tags: python, networkx

The python networkx module has a method nx.union for merging two network maps:

```
C = nx.union(G,H)
```

where G and H are network maps, and C in the combined version. It looks up all the nodes by number and merges nodes with the same number.

*Example of a node stored in GEXF format:*

```
  <node id="0" label="walking">
    <ns0:color b="200" g="11" r="11" />
    <attvalues>
      <attvalue for="0" value="2" />
      <attvalue for="1" value="26" />
    </attvalues>
  </node>
```

This is a problem for me, because my maps have arbitrary node numbers but unique labels in each node attribute. When I assign node numbers, I am just going through a list and using the list index as the node number, but map1 might have "walking" in position 84 and map2 might have "walking" in position 157 - so node numbers are not easy to relate to node labels.

Does anyone know how I am supposed to union to network maps with networkx and specify matching by node label names?

I probably have to write my own method, but just wanted to be sure I wasn't missing something. There is a union_disjoint() but that seems to create two separate unconnected maps in the same file, which isn't helpful.

Also 2nd networkx question: Is there a way to specify node label size and label color in the GEXF file format? Wasn't listed in the GEXF v1.2 draft specifications.

Comment: According to [the docs](http://networkx.lanl.gov/preview/reference/generated/networkx.union.html), `nx.union` assumes the graphs to be disjoint, so if I interpret correctly, it's not even supposed to work for your problem. Maybe [`nx.disjoint_union`](http://networkx.lanl.gov/preview/reference/generated/networkx.disjoint_union.html#networkx.disjoint_union) does what you want?

Comment: I tried disjoint_union already - when you build and viz in gephi, you get two completely separate graphs. I know it can be done, but appears to not be trivial given the way data must be structured in GEXF. It requires id#s as nodes when you add color and size attribs to nodes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using nx.read_gexf(file,relabel=True).  That will use the GEXF node labels as the NetworkX node identifiers.  Then you can merge the two graphs by adding the nodes and edges of one to the other. e.g.

```
>>> G = nx.read_gexf(file1, relabel=True)
>>> H = nx.read_gexf(file2, relabel=True)
>>> G.add_nodes_from(H.nodes(data=True))
>>> G.add_edges_from(H.edges(data=True))
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this and get back to you on whether it solves the problem.

Comment: I realize I never got back to answering this. I will try to test it this week. Has anyone else tried this?

Comment: Although this thread is pretty old, I can confirm that the above answer (the add_nodes/edges_from methods) is correct.